# Issue with System.Data.OracleClient and ODP.Net 11g together used in .net 2.0 web site

Tags: odp.net, system.data.oracleclient

In our .net framework 2.0 based application we were using System.Data.Oracleclient and now migrating to ODP.Net, the volume of the project is too high, 
so we cannot do the entire migration on one go, as a result the application is using 2 providers System.Data.Oracleclient & ODP.Net as of now.

Now we are changing our OS, from Windows xp 32bit to Windows 7 64bit. While doing so we observed the following,

1) A query executes in < 1 sec using System.Data.Oracleclient & ODP.Net 10g 64bit (Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 2.102.2.20).
and the same query executes in < 1 sec on Oracle SQL Developer v1.5.

2) However the same query is taking 2-3 mins to execute using System.Data.OracleClient with ODP.Net 11g 64bit (Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 2.112.3.0).

we found a remarkable performance degradation in point 2), 
we have to use System.Data.OracleClient with ODP.Net 11g 64bit (Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 2.112.3.0) on Windows 7 64bit OS, 
but we cannot live with the performance degradation as mentioned in point 2), 
and we cannot convert all code which uses System.Data.OracleClient to ODP.Net very quickly.

So can anyone help us, on why do we see such remarkable performance degradation as mentioned in point 2), and what do we do to resolve this problem.

Regards
Sanjib Harchowdhury

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer this [link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10838881), or just replace ODP.Net 64bit component with ODP.Net 32bit, as we are using asp.net we could easily configure our application to run using the 32bit component in Windows 7 (x64) edition.

Comment: If you're ok with your application running as 32 bit that's fine, but this effectively eliminates the memory addressing advantage a 64 bit OS has for your application.  I'd also consider this a fluke as I routinely reference and use both bit versions.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to your config will send odp.net tracing info to a log file:

```
  <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
      <add name="TraceFileName" value="c:\temp\odpnet-tests.trc"/>
      <add name="TraceLevel" value="63"/>
    </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

This will probably only be helpful if you can find a large gap in time.  Chances are rows are actually coming in, just at a slower pace.

**Try adding "enlist=false" to your connection string**.  I don't consider this a solution since it effecitively disables distributed transactions but it should help you isolate the issue.  You can get a little bit more information from an [oracle forumns post](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2284204):

> From an ODP perspective, all we can really point out is that the
>   behavior occurs when OCI_ATR_EXTERNAL_NAME and OCI_ATR_INTERNAL_NAME
>   are set on the underlying OCI connection (which is what happens when
>   distrib tx support is enabled).

I'd guess what you're not seeing is that the execution plan is actually different (meaning the actual performance hit is actually occuring on the server) between the odp.net call and the sql developer call.  Have your dba trace the connection and obtain execution plans from both the odp.net call and the call straight from SQL Developer (or with the enlist=false parameter).

If you confirm different execution plans or if you want to take a preemptive shot in the dark, **update the statistics on the related tables**.  In my case this corrected the issue, indicating that execution plan generation doesn't really follow different rules for the different types of connections but that the cost analysis is just slighly more pesimistic when a distributed transaction might be involved.  Query hints to force an execution plan are also an option but only as a last resort.

Finally, it could be a network issue.  If your odp.net install is using a fresh oracle home (which I would expect unless you did some post-install configuring) then the tnsnames.ora could be different.  Host names might not be fully qualified, creating more delays resolving the server.  I'd only expect the first attempt (and not subsequent attempts) to be slow in this case so I don't think it's the issue but I thought it should be mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, looking at the suggestion of Tracing, one thing when I replace ODP.Net 11g 64bit with ODP.Net 10g 64 bit in my laptop and execute the same query using System.Data.OracleClient component, everything is fine and normal, so cant say its a query execution or network related issue. I have raised this in ODP.Net forum too, hoping for any solution.

Comment: Did you try adding enlist=false to your connection string?

Comment: yes I tried with that option, it didn't help, but though I replaced ODP.Net 11g 64bit with ODP.Net 11g 32 bit, as mentioned in here, [link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10838881) and it worked. Thanks for your opinion too.

Comment: I'm wondering now if your 64 bit installation is simply corrupt.

Comment: Well my first thinking was on that line, for that I used another test website which was only using ODP.Net 64bit component. There I put the same query and it was working fine. I guess there is a problem in System.Data.OracleClient & ODP.Net 64 bit in 64bit Windows, most people probably using any one, not both in their applications, hence it may not be explored that way.