# ODP.Net - OracleDataReader.Read very slow

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, odp.net

I'm having a lot of trouble with the OracleDataReader in ODP.Net.  Basically, I have a parameterized query that takes anywhere from 1-5 seconds to run (returning around 450 records) and then takes 60-90 seconds to loop over (with no code even running in the loop, literally iterating over the recordset and doing nothing).

When I run it from Aqua Data Studio it takes 1-5 seconds.
When I run it from .Net it takes 1-5 seconds for cmd.ExecuteReader() to return.
When I loop over the 450 records with OracleDataReader.Read it takes 60-90 seconds to finish.

I even took out all of the code in the loop and just had a blank "While dr.Read" and it still took 60 to 90 seconds to loop over those 450 records (I used a Stopwatch to get the time for the cmd.ExecuteReader and then around the empty dr.Read loop).

I have tried setting the FetchSize, it didn't help (and, it's only 450 records in my test case).
I have tried turning auto tuning off with the connection string, it degraded performance even more.

Why is the OracleDataReader.Read taking so long when it's a small amount of data being returned (and other tools return the same data for the same query in a fraction of the time)?

```
    Using conn As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("oracle_dss").ConnectionString)                 
    conn.Open()
    Using cmd As OracleCommand = conn.CreateCommand
        cmd.BindByName = True
        cmd.CommandText = ""  ' removed SQL to make this more readable

        ' Month end
        Dim paramMonthEndDate As OracleParameter = cmd.CreateParameter
        paramMonthEndDate.ParameterName = ":month_end_date"
        paramMonthEndDate.DbType = DbType.Date
        paramMonthEndDate.Value = monthEnd
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramMonthEndDate)

        Dim sw As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
        sw.Start()

        cmd.FetchSize = 1000
        Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.FetchSize = dr.RowSize * 1000

        sw.Stop()
        Me.Log(String.Format("Month End Query: {0}s", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000))

        sw.Reset()
        sw.Start()

        While dr.Read

        End While

        sw.Stop()

        Me.Log(String.Format("Month End Query through recordset: {0}s", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000))

        dr.Close()
            End Using
    conn.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: Could you show your code.. perhaps you are doing something with opening and closing the connections basically too many round trips but can't tell without seeing any existing code. Also have you looked to see if the Query is `Hitting the Indexes` if any are on the table that you are querying

Comment: Let me get my code and I'll update the question.  It is indexed.. and it runs to completion in Aqua Data Studio (3rd party query utility) with all results returned in a couple of seconds.  I would think if the indexes weren't working that would also be an equivalent slow.

Comment: Are you certain about the server response time? There may also be an issue with the oracle configuration.

Comment: The SQL datareader is faster but that is a big difference.

Comment: I've timed each line of the .Net code with a Stopwatch and I've just read the execution time off of the 3rd party utility (and then scrolled through it's data grid to verify all the data was there).

Comment: I edited the question code above and added the .net code I ran.  I incorrectly tagged as C#, changed it to VB.

Comment: Maybe some strange locking.  Not sure of the Oracle syntax but in TSQL it is with (nolock).  Understand dirty reads may not be acceptable but this would indicate if it is a locking issue.  Did you try DataTable? The Oracle DataAdapter may not have the same problem.

Comment: Same result with a DataTable (just tried it).  Also, in this db, the data is loaded at night, no writes happen after it's loaded until the next night.  Researching locking/blocking currently.

Comment: Have you measured the time it takes to scroll to the bottom of the data grid in your third-party tool (Aqua Data Studio)? Can you do it instantaneously?

Comment: You can scroll to the bottom instantaneously in Aqua Data Studio running the same query.  It executes the query and loads all of the results into the grid within a second or two.

Comment: I would create a new table with just an Iden and put 1000 rows it.  Then loop over that table  to see if is table related.

Comment: If I just select * from any given table the issue doesn't occur.  In this case it's a query with sub queries.  I would have chalked it up to DB issues had it not performed so well through Aqua Data Studio (I removed the parameters and ran a verbatim query through both routes).  I'm going to see if I can get our DBA to try to get an explain on both routes to understand why they're performing different.  The actual ExecuteReader performs in a similiar time, it's the DataReader.Read that chokes.  I also made sure I had the latest ODP.Net provider today which I do.

Answer (score 0):

Work with your DBAs and ask them to capture an explain plan for both the stand alone run (aqua data studio) and your odp.net call and confirm they are in fact the same.  If they are not, then that will probably explain your problem.  You can then try adding "enlist=false" to your connection string but better yet have the DBA's update the statistics on the related tables, hopefully fixing the slow plan.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14712992/852208 for more info.

I have had this same issue and it came down to oracle being less optimistic about the execution plan when a distributed transaction could be involved.

Comment: I will go see if they can get a capture on both (also, I previously have added enlist=false to my connection string today).

Comment: What would be an example of something that would make Oracle be less optimistic?  Curious if I might be doing something to trigger it that I'm not realizing.

Comment: Appearently (from the post in the linked article), just having the possiblity of distributed connection is enough (which is the default for the connection).  In my case I was actually doing things in the context of a TransactionScope, but the oracle expert on the forum indicated that this wasn't even a requirement.  Once I realized the plans were different, updating the statistics fixed the issue. Luck maybe. The point is that the execution plan that oracle calculates for one connection maybe different than another so running the raw query outside of odp.net won't necessarily excuse the DB.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am wrong, but you actually fetch the data in this row:  `While dr.Read`, and not when you are executing the reader. So this can explain why even without doing nothing, `dr.Read` take all your time.

I'd try to change your command to

1). Run plain sql (without parameters)

2). Run using regular (not binding variable) parameter

3). Move the sql code to Stored Procedure if possible