# C# Can any one tell Best and Fastest way to Load data into DataTable

Tags: c#

Actually I am trying to export data from data table to excel sheet.
but it takes very long time to load huge data into Data Table . Is there any best and fastest way to fill the Data Table.

Here is my code which uses "dt.Load(reader)" to load into DT.

```
Stopwatch Timer = new Stopwatch();   
Timer.Start();
String cmdQuery = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Query"];
con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = CONN_STRING;
con.Open();

OracleCommand cmd=new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection=con;
cmd.CommandText=cmdQuery;
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();   


OracleDataReader odr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
Console.WriteLine("Got Data from Database...."); 
IDataReader reader=odr;               
Console.WriteLine("Loading into Data table....");              
dt.Load(reader);
Console.WriteLine("Time taken to load {0}...", Timer.Elapsed);

Workbook book = new Workbook();
Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];

Console.WriteLine("Inserting into Excel....");
sheet.InsertDataTable(dt, true, 1, 1);
Console.WriteLine("Time taken to insert into Excel {0}", Timer.Elapsed);

book.SaveToFile("C:\\New folder\\ExcelSheet.xls");
Timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Finished...."); 

Console.WriteLine("overall Time Taken {0}", Timer.Elapsed);
Console.WriteLine("Press Any key to exit");
Console.ReadLine();
```

It takes around 1 hour to load 50,000 records. I wanted to load hundreds of thousands of records to Data Table. So i hope the above code (dt.Load(reader)) wont work out for my requirement.

Also i tried with the below code which uses adapter to fill DT "Adapter.Fill(dt);":

```
Stopwatch Timer = new Stopwatch();   
Timer.Start();
String cmdQuery = " select * from temp_lse_not_matched";
con = new OracleConnection();
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
con.ConnectionString = CONN_STRING;
con.Open();

OracleDataAdapter Adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmdQuery, con);
Console.WriteLine("Got Data from Database...");

Console.WriteLine("Loading into Data table....");   
Adapter.Fill(dt);
Console.WriteLine("Time taken to load {0}...", Timer.Elapsed);

Workbook book = new Workbook();
Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];

Console.WriteLine("Inserting into Excel....");
sheet.InsertDataTable(dt, true, 1, 1);
Console.WriteLine("Time taken to insert into Excel {0}", Timer.Elapsed);               

book.SaveToFile("C:\\New folder\\ToExcel.xls");
Timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Finished....");
```

The above code also takes more time when compared to the 1st one.
So please Can any one help me on these..Can any one post the best way to load DT than the given above 2 method. Any post really appreciated.

Comment: Obviously there could be some improvment depending on how you try to fill it (the code) but in my opinion in this case the real improvment comes from the better hardware and the fastest connection. By changing different scenarios of fetching data you will only get minor differences. This is my opinion though.

Comment: There will be many reasons in your case. 1.The query you are using to get the data may take more time(Go for query optimization) 2. Lack of efficient code(go for code review) 3.Hardware issues 4. Network related issues in case if you are accessing a remote DataBase.

Comment: The fastest way is to fetch through DataReader from database, but as mention above more thing required like harware issues, network related issues in case of remote DB.

Comment: Does it take long to run the query direct on the db? It might not be this code at all.

Comment: when you are debugging the code where can observe slowness? is it at "Adapter.Fill(dt);"

Comment: @vallabha Yes , i debugged my code. slowness comes in this piece of code dt.Load(reader) and Adapter.Fill(dt).

Comment: @weston No . it did not take long time to run my query. And it was just a select query like 'select * from mytable';

Comment: Probably not a problem related to your own code. If it's not the sql query itself, maybe this could help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884433/odp-net-oracledatareader-read-very-slow

Answer (score 0):

There will be many reasons in your case.

1.The query you are using to get the data may take more time(Go for query optimization)

2.Network related issues in case if you are accessing a remote DataBase.

3.Hardware issues

4. Lack of efficient code(go for code review)

Comment: Yes i am using Remote Database. I am using select Query in my code. The problem is not there i guess. When i execute my query it will return result to OracleDataReader and it was not taking very long time(takes approx 1 min).But when i try to  load from OracleDataReader to Data Table it is taking very long time. So i guess dt.load(rdr) takes long time in my case.

Comment: @user3828470 The fastest way of reading is using SqlDataReader. Use the object of the class and fill. This might be helpfull. Becuse SqlDataReader is forward and readonly

Comment: Actually i am able to read the data from database in a faster way. But the problem is with loading into Data Table.

Comment: @SatheeshAppu May i know what is the size in MB's or else how many records are there in total

Comment: Hi Vallaba, there are totally 50400 records and it is taking 40 mins to load into DataTable.

Comment: @SatheeshAppu you said that you don't have any problem in retrieving the records. After 50,000 records sql performs slow

Comment: Vallaba , No. I said i could retrieve the data and store it into DataReader. but while loading the data into DataTable from DataReader it was taking long time.

Comment: @SatheeshAppu Have tried to prepare the `DataTable` manually without using `Load()' method

Comment: Vallaba. Can you please tell how to Prepare manually? As i guess it would be like using while or for loop if i am not wrong. If so, i have tried it before. It would also take more time than the above 2 methods. Please correct if i am wrong.

Comment: @SatheeshAppu yes i mean the same as you said, as you are saying it is taking more time than the above methods, can u go for caching?

Comment: @vallaba, Can you please tell how to use caching in c#?