# Oracle Bind Query is very slow

Tags: oracle, plsql, odp.net

I have an Oracle bind query that is extremely slow (about 2 minutes) when it executes in my C# program but runs very quickly in SQL Developer.  It has two parameters that hit the tables index:

```
select t.Field1, t.Field2
from theTable t
where t.key1=:key1
  and t.key2=:key2
```

Also, if I remove the bind variables and create dynamic sql, it runs just like it does in SQL Developer.

Any suggestion?

BTW, I'm using ODP.

Comment: I wonder if it's something to do with different optimizer settings (eg. first_rows vs all_rows) in c# vs sql developer. See [this article by Tom Kyte](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-may/o38asktom-085659.html) for more info. Maybe you could check v$sql and v$sql_shared_cursor to see if you've got multiple rows for the same sql statement and if so, whether different optimizer modes is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you are replacing the bind variables with static varibles in sql developer, then you're not really running the same test.  Make sure you use the bind varibles, and if it's also slow you're just getting bit by a bad cached execution plan.  Updating the stats on that table should resolve it.

However if you are actually using bind variables in sql developers then keep reading.  The TLDR version is that parameters that ODP.net run under sometimes cause a slightly more pessimistic approach.  Start with updating the stats, but have your dba capture the execution plan under both scenarios and compare to confirm.

I'm reposting my answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14712992/852208
I considered flagging yours as a duplicate but your title is a little more concise since it identifies the query does run fast in sql developer.  I'll welcome advice on handling in another manner.

Adding the following to your config will send odp.net tracing info to a log file:

This will probably only be helpful if you can find a large gap in time. Chances are rows are actually coming in, just at a slower pace.

Try adding "enlist=false" to your connection string. I don't consider this a solution since it effecitively disables distributed transactions but it should help you isolate the issue. You can get a little bit more information from an oracle forumns post:

> From an ODP perspective, all we can really point out is that the
>   behavior occurs when OCI_ATR_EXTERNAL_NAME and OCI_ATR_INTERNAL_NAME
>   are set on the underlying OCI connection (which is what happens when
>   distrib tx support is enabled).

I'd guess what you're not seeing is that the execution plan is actually different (meaning the actual performance hit is actually occuring on the server) between the odp.net call and the sql developer call. Have your dba trace the connection and obtain execution plans from both the odp.net call and the call straight from SQL Developer (or with the enlist=false parameter).

If you confirm different execution plans or if you want to take a preemptive shot in the dark, update the statistics on the related tables. In my case this corrected the issue, indicating that execution plan generation doesn't really follow different rules for the different types of connections but that the cost analysis is just slighly more pesimistic when a distributed transaction might be involved. Query hints to force an execution plan are also an option but only as a last resort.

Finally, it could be a network issue. If your odp.net install is using a fresh oracle home (which I would expect unless you did some post-install configuring) then the tnsnames.ora could be different. Host names in tnsnams might not be fully qualified, creating more delays resolving the server. I'd only expect the first attempt (and not subsequent attempts) to be slow in this case so I don't think it's the issue but I thought it should be mentioned.

Comment: I'm copying the sql from the application and keeping the bind variables in tact.

Answer (score 1):

Are the parameters bound to the correct data type in C#?  Are the columns `key1` and `key2` numbers, but the parameters `:key1` and `:key2` are strings?  If so, the query may return the correct results but will require implicit conversion.  That implicit conversion is like using a function `to_char(key1)`, which prevents an index from being used.

Comment: The fields key1 and key2 are CHAR(8) and CHAR(2), respectively.  The parameters are CHAR(8) and CHAR(2) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please also check what is the number of rows returned by the query. If the number is big then possibly C# is fetching all rows and the other tool first pocket only. Fetching all rows may require many more disk reads in that case, which is slower. To check this try to run in SQL Developer:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    select t.Field1, t.Field2
      from theTable t
     where t.key1=:key1
       and t.key2=:key2
)
```

The above query should fetch the maximum number of database blocks.

Nice tool in such cases is tkprof utility which shows SQL execution plan which may be different in cases above (however it should not be).

It is also possible that you have accidentally connected to different databases. In such cases it is nice to compare results of queries.

Since you are raising "Bind is slow" I assume you have checked the SQL without  binds and it was fast. In 99% using binds makes things better. Please check if query with constants will run fast. If yes than problem may be implicit conversion of key1 or key2 column (ex. t.key1 is a number and :key1 is a string).

Comment: The number of records are low.  Between 10 and 100.